# downloading a zip file from URL in wcf c#

Tags: c#, wcf, httprequest, uri, webclient

I am trying to download a zip folder from a url. The url points to a library in Sharepoint containing a document set. If the url is pasted in browser it downloads a zip file. While trying to do the same from code i am able to download only 32426 bytes. I tried two approaches - one the DownloadDataAsync() using WebClient and other the WebRequest and response. Both these read only 32426 bytes whereas the zip folder is in close to 6 MB.

```
using (var Webclient1 = new WebClient())
{
    Webclient1.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
    Webclient1.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");

    byte[] data = null;
    Webclient1.DownloadDataCompleted +=
    delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        data = e.Result;
    };

    Webclient1.DownloadDataAsync(uri);
    while (Webclient1.IsBusy)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    var len = data.Length;
}
```

Using HttpRequest and response

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
//request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Accept = @"text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";

request.Timeout = 1000000;
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    stream.CopyTo(stream2);
    return stream2.ToArray();
}
```

Both read incomplete content.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public bool DownloadFile(string itemUrl, string localPath)
        {
            bool downloadSuccess = false;

            try
            {
                using (IOFile.Stream itemFileStream = GetItemAsStream(itemUrl))
                {
                    using (IOFile.Stream localStream = IOFile.File.Create(localPath))
                    {
                        itemFileStream.CopyTo(localStream);
                        downloadSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {

            }

            return downloadSuccess;
        }


protected IOFile.Stream GetItemAsStream(string itemUrl)
        {
            IOFile.Stream stream = null;
            try
            {
                FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(_context, itemUrl);
                stream = fileInfo.Stream;                
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Error executing method {0}. {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, err.Message));
            }

            return stream;
        }
```